# Under what scenarios does it make sense to share a single AWS VPC Endpoint for multiple RestAPIs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

Based on the documentation, I know that 1 single VPC Endpoint can be shared for multiple API Gateway RestAPIs ( Private)

> Each endpoint can be used to access multiple private APIs.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html

This option is interesting in that ( I believe) it offers the potential to minimize unnecessary resources. For example, say I have 50 private micro-services, and they are each sitting behind a dedicated RestAPI. If I re-use the VPC Endpoint for all 50 apis, then perhaps I can simplify the URLs that are provided to API developers/consumers.
Said another way, if I create dedicated VPC Endpoint per RestAPI, that means the API consumers need to understand many more VPC Endpoint configurations. Is this correct?

When exactly does it make sense to share VPC Endpoints?

When doesn't it make sense to share VPC Endpoints?

Any insights are appreciated. Just hoping to get some insights so I understand if I *need* to create unique VPC endpoints per RestAPI.

Answer (score 1):

A VPC Endpoint is really just giving resources in your VPC access to the AWS API Gateway service. That allows resources in your VPC to access any APIs managed by API Gateway. It's very rare that you would need to create more than one of these per VPC. The only reason I can think of creating more than one is if you have some complicated VPC configuration where certain subnets need access to an API, while different subnets need access to a different API, and you wanted to manage that access via VPC route tables.

Comment: Ok perfect, so based on this, your saying: For multiple RestAPIs, its likely the use of a single VPC and a single VPC Endpoint for all RestAPIs is the most optimal setup, correct? Or at least the more common?

Comment: Said another way, it sounds like a good rule of thumb for a set of private microservices is to use single VPC endpoint with single VPC. Please correct me if Im wrong.